# How to run haproxy within Docker on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: docker, haproxy

Total noob here, so many thanks for your patience in advance.

My goal is to create a reverse proxy on an rpi3. I've managed to install haproxy on it, configure haproxy.cfg to handle respective traffic accordingly.

My understanding is that this is best run within a "Docker container", presumably to allow to run the proxy on startuo and make the proxy run more like a service than anything.

How can I go about running this haproxy within Docker on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Thank you,

Comment: There is a Raspberry PI SE you should research this on.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but it doesn't seem safe. Especially with raspberry pi limited resources. Which raspberry pi os are you planning on using in your container? Try to find the lightest one possible.